# Android get data from dynamic url from APi

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

I found some Api about Pokemon(https://pokeapi.co). And I try get data from this Api and it's work.
The data look like this

[image]

But I try to use **name** of data from Api to get some image with this path **"api/v2/pokemon/{name}"**

The problem is how can get name out of onResponse or do the other way to get **name** and **image** of Pokemon

MainActivity

```
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://pokeapi.co/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(HTTPLogger.getLogger())
                .build()
        val jsonPlaceholderApi = retrofit.create(pokemonService::class.java)
        val myCall: Call<PokemonInGen> = jsonPlaceholderApi.getGen(1)

        myCall.enqueue(object : Callback<PokemonInGen> {
            override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<PokemonInGen>,
                    response: Response<PokemonInGen>
            ) {
                val DataResponse: PokemonInGen = response.body()!!

                Timber.i("on do Respon %s", DataResponse)


            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<PokemonInGen>, t: Throwable) {
                Timber.i("on do ERROR")
            }

        })
```

My Service

```
interface pokemonService {


    @GET("api/v2/generation/{id}")
    fun getGen(
            @Path("id") id: Int,
    ): Call<PokemonInGen>


    @GET("api/v2/pokemon/{name}")
    fun getArtwork(
            @Path("name") name: String,
    ): Call<PokemonArtwork>


}
```

My Model Data class

```
data class PokemonInGen(
        val pokemon_species: List<PokemonList>)

data class PokemonList(
        val name: String,
        val url: String,
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch Pokemon image you should create additional function in your `MainActivity` class

```kotlin
fun fetchPokemonArtwork(name: String) {
    jsonPlaceholderApi.getArtwork(name).enqueue(object : Callback<PokemonArtwork> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<PokemonArtwork>,
            response: Response<PokemonArtwork>
        ) {
            // An artwork is successful fetched
            val artwork = response.body()!!
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<PokemonArtwork>, t: Throwable) {
            // Handle a failure
        }
    })
}
```

You should call this function right after you fetched a Pokemon in generation

```kotlin
val myCall: Call<PokemonInGen> = jsonPlaceholderApi.getGen(1)
myCall.enqueue(object : Callback<PokemonInGen> {
    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<PokemonInGen>,
        response: Response<PokemonInGen>
    ) {
        val DataResponse: PokemonInGen = response.body()!!
        
        Timber.i("on do Respon %s", DataResponse)

        // Extract name
        val name = DataResponse.pokemon_species.first().name

        // Fetch an artwork
        fetchPokemonArtwork(name)
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<PokemonInGen>, t: Throwable) {
        Timber.i("on do ERROR")
    }
})
```

P.S. I proceeded from the assumption that you've implemented `PokemonArtwork` class. Please let me know if you are facing difficulties in comments below.

P.S.S. It's not recommended to make network calls in `Activity` or `Fragment` classes. [This guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) should help you to select correct app structure in your future releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `@Url` to support dynamic link in retrofit. Example below:

```
interface pokemonService {
    @GET
    Call<PokemonResponse> getListPokemon(@Url String url);
}
```

And paste your url to browser to see data format.

Comment: Can you show how to create getListPokemon and PokemonResponse

Comment: @BBBBeloved this is just example to show how to use `@Url` you need modify code to adapt your logic

Comment: old code get the same output but the problem is how i get the data from url dynamicly or not just a name and url

Comment: @BBBBeloved Please paste that url to browser and you see format of response. I tried and see response is Json format. And then, you can declare models adapt Json

Comment: I want only pokemon gen 1 [link](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/generation/1)